# How to remove a rectangular region at the centre

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to remove a portion of the video between say coordinates (x,y) and (m,n), where (x,y) are the upper left coordinates while (m,n) are the lower right ones. Is there a ffmpeg command I could use?

Comment: Do you want to overlay an opaque box on top?

Comment: Basically yeah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the drawbox filter to umm. draw a box on top of the video.

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawbox=X:Y:M-X:N-Y:c=black:t=fill" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

where X, Y are replaced with top-left co-ordinates of box. `M-X` and `N-Y` are width and height of the box. The value `fill` for thickness will make a solid box. This value was very recently changed, so if you have an older version of ffmpeg, use `max` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Can I simply replace fill with max or does max have a different syntax, sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: Yes, simply replace fill with max.